# Using EF with a legacy Oracle database (with stored procedures)?

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

I am curious if anyone has some thoughts on whether or not moving to the Entity Framework is worthwhile for a department working with a large legacy Oracle database and mandated stored procedure use?

Many of our tables do not have numerical primary keys and some use composite keys.

I gave the Entity Framework version of ODP.NET a try when it was in beta and was not impressed.  Calling stored procedures was no cleaner than with regular ODP and the framework was not able to automatically generate mappings between the stored procedures and POCO objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whether or not moving to the entity framework is worthwhile for a department working with a large legacy Oracle database and mandated stored procedure use?

It will require a lot of up front work to tune your EDM to work with the client application that currently utilize your Oracle database.

However, EF 5.0 is much robust in features and capabilities than 2 years ago. It has Code first feature, where you may still use your POCO objects and map them to Entities that are retrieved through usage of stored procs. Btw, starting from EF4, there is a stored procedure and function support.